# How to make a "clean wineprefix" in a terminal?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, wine

I'm trying to install wmp10 through Wine so I can use the digital library accessing programme Overdrive. (Installing wmp10 through PlayOnLinux doesn't enable the DRM that allows Overdrive to work, hence the need to install it through Wine. Also, wmp isn't available through the GUI version of Winetricks that I have.)

Apparently I need to create a "clean wineprefix" first, but I don't know how to do that. Running the following code didn't work:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine.tmp wineprefixcreate
```

Can someone give some very simple instructions showing how to make a clean wineprefix? And how to then install wmp10 from within the new prefix?

Ubuntu 14.04, XFCE interface, Wine 1.7.38, 32-bit

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on having more than one alternative prefix, I'd recommend keeping a directory of prefixes (e.g., `~/.wine/wineprefix/<nameofprefix>`). In your case of only needing one prefix, let's call our alternative wineprefix "`.wine-w-wmp`":

```
mkdir ~/.wine-w-wmp
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-w-wmp wine winecfg
```

The wineprefix part tells the `wine` program which virtual drive to use. `wine winecfg` is the actual command, which will bring up the virtual drive's configuration. However, winecfg will notice that no virtual drive exists at this new location and will create one. Wine "bottles"/"wineprefixes" and "virtual drives" are used interchangeably--they refer to a new instance of `wine`, like separate computers with their own setup. So this is your clean wineprefix.

---

In your case, to install Windows Media Player 10, download it from [their website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20426), and if the file is in your Downloads folder, run:

```
WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-w-wmp wine ~/Downloads/MP10Setup.exe
```

Then install as usual.

---

If you're planning to type `WINEPREFIX=<directory of prefix>` at the start of each wine command, you might want to just set that wineprefix as the default. (When run without "WINEPREFIX=", `wine` looks to its default wineprefix at `~/.wine`.) To change the default (at least until your next restart), run:

```
export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine-w-wmp <or the directory of your prefix>
```

(If you want this command to stick between new Terminal instances, add the above line to your `~/.bashrc` and then run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the file in your current instance.)

Answer (score 0):

To create a wineprefix called wineprefix, the command I used was:

`WINEPREFIX=/home/[name]/wineprefix winetricks dotnet40 corefonts`

I was given guidance about this at https://forum.winehq.org. Instructions are available under the FAQ section there: http://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#32_bit_wineprefix.

Comment: This assume that winetricks is installed and the user need dotnet40 and corefonts installed